# Laravel-4 automatically send email to users on daily basis

Tags: email, laravel-4, newsletter

I am creating a `laravel` website and i want to send email to all the users once in a day for 3 days.
Is there any package which can do this??

Comment: You could also use cronjob to do that task, you have to run that cron task through Command.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking to do is run a cron job - and pull the recent signups from there.

A package which can help you in Laravel 4 is https://github.com/Indatus/dispatcher

In Laravel 5 this package functionality will be built into the framework automatically.